# How to store array cookie in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.4

I have this function in laravel 5.4 but I get error.

```
$cart[$product->id] = $quantity;
var_dump($cart);
return redirect('catalogs')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('cart', $cart));
```

var_dump($cart) contains this:

```
array(1) { [1]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Error warning:

```
Method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Array to string conversion
```

If I passed just string value (not array), it success. If there any way to store array cookie in Laravel?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried serializing the array?

Comment: Yeah, serialize($cart) is the answer. Although I hope Laravel framework can handle storing array in cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only strings can be stored in a cookie. So try this:

```
$cart[$product->id] = $quantity;
var_dump($cart);
return redirect('catalogs')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('cart', serialize($cart)));
```

Comment: Good idea. Thank you for explanation that only strings can be stored in a cookie, even with Laravel framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Warning: Do not use serialize/unserialize
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#refsect1-function.unserialize-notes

You can store it as JSON

```
 $user=['name'=>'Imran','email'=>'xyz*emphasized text@gmail.com'];
 $array_json=json_encode($user);
 return redirect('user')->withCookie(cookie()->forever( 'user',$array_json, 450000));
```

On retrieval

```
 $user=\Cookie::get('user');
       $user=json_decode($user);
echo $user->name;
echo $user->email;
```