# Laravel Cookie interferes with Session and Auth

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

Currently I'm having a simple form and when I post the form I will set some variables but also want to keep this values for a next time so the user don't have to fill in all form input values.

Now what I'm doing is the following:

```
use Cookie;

public function setCookieAndHandleFormData(){
    // Handle all form data and store in $form_data
    $form_data = setFormData(); // This is handled correctly (just an array of key values)

    Cookie::queue('cookie_data', $form_data, 43200); // set a cookie
    Session::put('session_data', $form_data); // set a session
}
```

When I'm executing above code I will get a lot of problems in Laravel 5.2

Functions like **Auth::user()** and **Session::get()** will stop functioning. Can anyone explain what is happening? And if I'm using the wrong approach here or something else is happening?

Comment: Do you have any Response following the `Cookie::queue()` call?

Comment: @lesssugar Yes. I've noticed that the array I'm saving is causing the problem. A single value stored in the cookie is handled perfectly. I will update my question with the array.

Comment: Right. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872142/how-to-store-array-cookie-in-laravel-5-4).

Comment: @lesssugar Seems like it's an other issue, even an array with strings causes the application to interfere with Auth and Session. When I remove Cookie::queue('cookie_data', $form_data, 43200); everything works again so it must have to do something with it.

Comment: Did you try to `serialize()` the array before you store it as the cookie value, like the post I linked to suggests? Still breaks it?

Comment: @lesssugar Yep. I tried to use a cookie with a single value stored again. It work like +-10 page reloads than it also breaks. Not sure what is going on. When I remove the Cookie no problem occurs but than I can't store values when I close my browser for a single session value?

Comment: A session value will be preserved, unless (1) the session gets flushed (e.g. on logout), (2) user clears the cookies, (3) the Laravel session expires. I don't know why the cookie part is causing problems, but I'd say you don't need the cookie at all. Instead, store the form data in the session only and retrieve it from there. The information will be kept until one of the actions I mentioned occurs. Also, you can preserve the session value before you flush the session if you need the data available for a guest user as well.

Comment: @lessugar Hmm... Is it also possible to mark a session to exist after the browser is closed? All my other session will expire when I close the browser (required).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152955/discussion-between-lesssugar-and-lars-mertens).