# How to set and get array into cookie in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, cookies

here i'm  try to set and get the array cookie with laravel 6, so here i'm try this code

this function to set the cookie

```
public function booking(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'name_package'=>$request->name_package,
            'price'=>$request->price,
        ];
        $array_json=json_encode($data);

        return redirect('/checkout')->withCookie(cookie()->forever( 'data',$array_json, 2880));
    }
```

here function to get the cookie

```
public function checkout(){
        $data=\Cookie::get('data');
        $data=json_decode($data);

        return view('home/checkout')->with('data', $data);;
    }
```

in my blade, im try to foreach the $data like this 
http://prntscr.com/qubpuy

but i got an error **Trying to get property 'name_package' of non-object**

pelase help me to correct this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store array cookie in laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872142/how-to-store-array-cookie-in-laravel-5-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is not in a cookie but in the blade file in foreach loop.

Your array name is `$data` and your alias name is `$data` so that is the same.

```
foreach($data as $data)
```

Replace it with a different name as below.

```
@foreach($data as $d)
    {{ $d->name_package ?? '' }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i've been change as $data into $d and put ?? '' in echo, but there no data that showing

Comment: debug it that value is exist in `$request->name_package`?

Comment: oke i'ts work sir, now i have problem, my input value was null, i set the value of input using ajax, for example the value of input price will be set if i change or select an select option. but when i'm try to post that form that value was null

Comment: try this  $d->name_package to   $d['name_package']   as you decode that then you will get array not an Object so by [] you can acess value

Comment: @KamleshPaul he used `json_decode($data);` that means he'll get an object not an array. if he would use `json_decode($data,true);` then it'll return an array.

Comment: @DilipHirapara ohh thank you man i didn't know the difference  tell him to do `json_decode($data,true);` because that object one may be not working

Comment: this problem is solved sir, i got a new problem to get value from input that value i get using ajax, can you answer this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960640/cant-get-input-value-from-ajax-when-submit-using-method-post

Comment: @DidikAriyana Select this answer as if this solution is worked for you for the question. Consider as true. Happy coding :)